# How to map multiple AWS LoadBalancer ports to a single instance port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have setup like this -- Two ports on my load balancer map to a single port on my instance (the instance checks the HTTP header and issues a HTTP redirect to the HTTPS site for any non HTTPS request). The AWS dashboard shows:

```
LB Proto| LB Port| Inst Proto| Inst Port| SSL Cert
---------------------------------------------------
HTTP    | 80     | HTTP      | 8080     | N/A   
HTTPS   | 443    | HTTP      | 8080     | my_ssl_cert
```

On my instance, I can inspect the incoming traffic as follows:

```
sudo ngrep -q -d eth0 -W byline port 8080
```

This succeeds: (https to the load balancer)

```
curl -k https://111.111.111.111/
```

but this fails: (http to the load balancer)

```
curl     http://111.111.111.111/
```

(where 111.111.111.111 is the loadbalancer's IP)

Curl stalls and times out, and I never see activity on port 8080 on my instance with ngrep (I do when I send the first request).

What's up? How come my loadbalancer isn't forwarding ANY traffic received on port 80 to port 8080 on my instance?

Comment: Neither of those should work at all, with the `www.` in the ELB URL.

Comment: My bad. Problems still persists though. Updating the question.

Comment: Does your ELB's security group allow 80?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed [in comments](https://serverfault.com/questions/638670/how-to-map-multiple-aws-loadbalancer-ports-to-a-single-instance-port#comment769928_638670), your issue was that your Load Balance security group was not configured to allow incoming requests at port 80.

Comment: Ah! that was my problem as well